# Accessing Biztalk server 2006 from Biztalk server 2010 Mgmt console

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Is it possible to access BizTalk Server 2006 MgmtDb from BizTalk Server 2010 management console?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I tried it still it didn't work. Few more things to add up is BizTalk server 2006 is 32 bit version and BizTalk 2010 is a 64bit version running on windows 7 64bit OS. So does this impose any constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is using the [standard MMC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578089.aspx) (Microsoft Management Console) there is no reason it shouldn't. I have not verified this though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. BizTalk administration console snap In is pointing to its own biztalk/sql version.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Microsoft Management Console is used for connect to BizTalk server. The SNAP IN (BizTalk Administrative console) used to connect to BizTalk Server relevant to respective version. So you cannot connect.